# Make Apache wait longer before delivering HTTP 408 request timeout

Tags: apache-2.2, php, configuration, fastcgi, cgi

My configuration:
Apache 2.2.4
PHP 5.2.4 (fastCGI)
Windows XP pro

I have a script that takes more than a minute to run but after exactly 60 seconds (proven by Fiddler) the server always delivers a 408 timeout. My PHP max execution time is set to 120 seconds. After doing some reading I've tried putting a "Timeout 120" directive in my Apache config file though I'm not confident that directive relates to what I'm trying to do. No dice. Is there any way to make apache wait longer before returning the 408? (Yes, I've restarted the web server between making config changes). Many thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488425/make-apache-wait-longer-before-delivering-http-408-request-timeout